# Multiple IF, AND, OR statements

Tags: excel

I am trying to create an Excel formula that would represent this logic:

```
If (B8 < 0 & A8 > 0), B8+A8  OR 
If (B8 < 0 & A8 < 0), B8-A8  OR 
If (B8 > 0 & A8 > 0), B8-A8
```

I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, following what you put more closely/literally:

```
=IF(AND(B8<0,A8>0),B8+A8, IF(AND(B8<0,A8<0), B8-A8, IF(AND(B8>0,A8>0), B8-A8, "null?" )))
```

Should do the trick.  Wasn't sure what to put if none of those cases fail, so just showing "null?" .. change that as desired.

(but I suspect pascx64's is more efficient in the long run ;) )

Answer (score 0):

`IF( B8 < 0, IF( A8 > 0, B8 + A8, B8 - A8 ), IF( A8 > 0, B8-A8, ?? ) )`

Your conditions does not handle what happen if B8 > 0 and A8 < 0 or if values are equal to 0 ( not greater, not smaller )